# UITableView with HeaderView not scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a screen holding some `UIElements` and a `UITableView` underneath.
In order to make everything scrollable, I implemented a `UITableView` and a `tableHeaderView` which contains the `UIElements`.

Now the View is not properly scrollable to display all `UITableViewCells`.

This are steps I have followed so far:

1. Programatically created `UIView` and it's `Subviews`
2. Set the custom `UIView` to `table.tableHeaderView`
3. Loaded the `data`.

What exactly am I missing?

**Edit: Code of the three steps**

1,2.
        let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

```
    imageSliderVC = TNImageSliderViewController()
    imageSliderVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.width)


    layerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.width))
    layerView.alpha = 0.25
    layerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    noButton = constructNopeButton()
    yesButton = constructLikedButton()
    buttonOptionsApply()

    nameLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, layerView.frame.maxY + 20, bounds.width-40, 20))
    nameLbl.makeNameLabelFormat()
    hashtagLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, nameLbl.frame.maxY + 5, bounds.width-40, layerView.frame.width/3.66))
    hashtagLbl.makeHashtagFormat()

    seperatorLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, hashtagLbl.frame.maxY + 15, bounds.width-40, 1))
    seperatorLbl.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x9B9B9B)

    groupsLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, seperatorLbl.frame.maxY + 15, 30, 20))
    groupsLbl.text = "Groups:"
    groupsLbl.makeNameLabelFormat()
    groupsLbl.sizeToFit()

    groupsCountLbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(groupsLbl.frame.maxX + 5, seperatorLbl.frame.maxY + 15 , 40, 20))
    groupsCountLbl.sizeToFit()

    let myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,bounds.width, groupsCountLbl.frame.maxY + 10))

    myView.addSubview(imageSliderVC.view)
    myView.addSubview(layerView)
    myView.addSubview(noButton)
    myView.addSubview(yesButton)
    myView.addSubview(nameLbl)
    myView.addSubview(hashtagLbl)
    myView.addSubview(seperatorLbl)
    myView.addSubview(groupsLbl)
    myView.addSubview(groupsCountLbl)



    table.tableHeaderView = myView
```

Comment: Could you show your code for those 3 steps?

Comment: I have edited everything. I don't think the data loading is necessary though

Comment: Are you sure your table's scrollEnabled is set to true?

Comment: @penatheboss yes, I have. It is scrollable, at least a bit, but not the whole size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the this problem by implementing a `UITableViewController` rather than a normal `UIViewController` with a `TableView` in IB